# Forced Hot Air temp out of vents seems too hot

Tags: hvac

Vents close to heater the temp is up to 130 F. Others further away are less than 100. 130 F just seems so hot that the metal register would burn your hand if you left it touching. The heater has to run over 7 minutes to reach this high temp.

Comment: Furnace, not boiler. Are the filters clean? Dirty filters can reduce airflow and cause higher temperatures as a result of moving less air...

Comment: Check for open positions of dampers on vents to "cooler" rooms.

Comment: I agree with both filters and damper positions, when I set up a system I verify flow in each zone with an a hand held ananometer I make sure the air speed is matched. If the registers are the same size the ones closer will have a higher flow so they need to be reduced most of the time. The last one on a line we usually run the trunk past it or it will have higher flow and noise. This is with a properly sized system.

Comment: Are you sure the blower is working?  if the belt breaks or the blower isn't blowing the air then the closest registers will definitely be the hottest.

Answer (score 1):

Add inlet area with filter to the furnace. This permits more air to flow over the furnace tubes. The furnace will be putting out about the same amount of heat but it will have a larger amount of air so the air temperature will not be as high. And as commented, make certain all dampers are open; there may be dampers in the ducts not just at the outlet grills.

Comment: Won’t down vote as it could be part of the problem, however if the system was properly sized I could create this problem in any forced air house by mis adjusting the dampers.